How to cut 1/4" plywood "skin" that is attached to a cabinet
I have a 1/4" thick "skin" attached to a kitchen cabinet turned into an island. It's glued pretty well, and I just need to neatly cut off a 6" vertical strip of it for what I need to do. The cabinet is secured to the floor and can't be moved. What is the best way to remove this 6-inch strip without damaging the 1/2" plywood of the cabinet underneath?
So far, I am thinking of using a hand router. My 7-1/4" circular saw is too big. Any other idea?

The glue will make this more difficult if just removing the covering.  Will need to know what the glue is and find a removal for it.

The tool to use for this job is an Oscillating saw.
(This tool is essential for any serious DIYer.)
Mark a line and use both hands to steady the saw.  I have added a few layers of tape to the blade to mark the depth I wanted and prevent going too deep with the cut. Use both hands to control the saw and start with the blade at a slight angle with light pressure. Once you get a bit of a line started it will help guide you.

I do have an oscillating saw; just don't know how I can make a very clean straight cut with it...

I added some techniques to my answer.

If those techniques didn’t work, you could temporarily attach a stick with double sided tape to act as a fence. Also, if you gave more context, we’d probably be able to suggest methods to hide a crappy cut.

You can also get what is effectively a mini circular saw.  Set the blade depth to a smidge under 1/4".  You still have to deal with the glue though.  Maybe a heat gun?
